# Tensor methods for representations of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, tensors

I'm familiar with the Young Tableaux method for finding irreducible representations of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and I also know of the tensor methods for finding irreducible representations of $\mathrm{SU}(3)$.

Tensor methods for $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ seem to rely heavily on the fact that irreducible representations of this group are identified by two natural numbers $(p,q)$, which define the covariance and contravariance of the tensor associated with that representation. But, if I'm not wrong, and, $n-1$ are needed to identify every irreducible representation of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$. I have no proof of this but it makes sense if we look at the Young Tableaux method.

My questions, then, are:

- Do tensor methods for finding irreducible representations of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ exist for $n > 3$?
- If so, which are those?
- If not, how is it that they exist for $n \leq 3$, why do they work?

Comment: The irreducible representations are determined by their restriction to a maximal torus which has dimension $n-1$, these are the weights.

Comment: Yes, these are the Dynkin indices: the number of single boxes, two-box columns, 3-box columns...etc. You want a tutorial? [Slansky 1981](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf).